# Android screen in different resolutions

Tags: android, resolution, screens

I want to develop an app which will support different screen sizes.

I've read the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) a lot of times, but I can not understand this.  I created a brand new app with a main activity, then I put a black square on the screen with 100dp x 100dp dimensions, just like this:

res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this application on my emulator - I get this screen:
[image]

And when I run the application on my device (Galaxy tab 2), I get a screen like this:
[image]

As you can see, the square running on device is smaller than running on the emulator.

I am using DP in my XML width and height.  Is the square supposed to be in the same proportion in all resolutions?  If not, what can I do to get this square in the same size in all resolutions?

Comment: different devices have different dp so if u manually put the dp like in ur case the 100dp it will consider the 100dp that has been allotted by the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be confusing.
However, different devices have different amounts of 'DP's. The purpose of this is so that larger screens can hold more content. If you're using images, you can provide different sizes for different screen densities.

For more info, see this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: in fact, only using dp in my xml, will not draw in the same size proportion in different DPs devices?

Comment: That's correct. You won't easily be able to get the same proportions across different devices, so it's best to use the guide mentioned in my post.

Comment: I don't understand what anyone is talking about here. If you use DPs then when you measure this thing with a ruler it should be exactly the same size regardless of device. Isn't that the whole point? Saying "different devices have different DPs" is a confusing way of putting it. Different devices have different number of pixels and density, but they have the same DPs because that's what it means: it's INDEPENDENT of the device. For example 1dp is 1px on an mdpi device, whereas its 1.5 pixels on an HDPI device.

Comment: @luxurymode I think you're confusing density with size.  Not all pixels are the same. Smaller pixels equals higher density.  It has nothing to do with the physical size of the screen.  What you are looking for is a way to size your image proportionally to its parent.  Check layout_weight in linearlayout

Comment: @JasonHessley Hmmm... I thought the whole point of DPs is exactly that: different screens have different number of pixels per area and the higher the density, the more pixels. But android categorizes things in terms of generalized densities and, while its true there's a range within each DPI category, when you use DP units, the system gives you the number of pixels you need in order to achieve that unit of DPs. So, in the end, if you have, say, some margin defined as 6dp, then the margin, when measured with a ruler should look the same on the Tmobile g1 and the galaxy nexus, for example.

Comment: In the end, using DP in XML layout positions and scales does not help much when working with different screens. DP is just a virtual calc that android uses to 'facilitate' the screen development based on the resolution and the DPI device (px = dp * (dpi / 160)), following this rule, even if you did your measures using DP and works great in a 160 dpi device for example, if you put the same app in a 320 DPI device, all the views will look 100% smaller, then what you have to do to fix this is create a another folder (layout-xlarge) and put your new xml design with the DP adjustments. Am I right?